# Ruby Shoes GUI set port don't work with thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, shoes

If I don't use a thread, I can normally use `@which_port.text.to_i` in port declaration. If I use a thread, it looks like this statement `@which_port.text.to_i` don't work. I can only write port manually, e.g. `6000` and then my program works good. I have to use thread because my program freezes otherwise. Is any way able to use `@which_port.text.to_i` despite the use thread?

```
require 'socket'
require 'thread'

Shoes.app do

def write
    @t = TCPSocket.new("xx.xx.xx.xx", @which_port.text.to_i)
    loop do
        msg = @t.recv(4096)
        @pa1.text = @pa1.text + msg
    end
end 

@btn = button("button", width: 80, height: 50) do
    window(left: 300, top: 300) do
    @pa1 = para ""
    @th1 = Thread.new { write }
   end
end

@e_ln = edit_line(width: 320, height: 25, margin_top: 5)

@which_port = list_box :items => ["5000", "6000", "7000"],
    :width => 120,
    :choose => "5000" do |list| 
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Add the error to your question, "don't work" is too vague.

Comment: I can't tell what you changed. But take the error message you get from the program and add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you launch a **window** you are launching a totally new app so variables in that new app are unknown to the other app, and those in the first app, the one that fired the window method are unknown to the new app ! Fortunately there is a **owner** method available in every Shoes app, in your case owner called inside the new app gives you a reference to the first app, the one that owns the new app !
One way to do what you want (Threading or not):

```
Shoes.app title: "Main Shoes app" do
    def write(paragr)
        msg = "#{self.inspect} === #{@which_port.text}"
        paragr.text = paragr.text + msg
    end

    @btn = button("button", width: 80, height: 50) do
        window(left: 300, top: 300, title: "Another Shoes app") do
            @pa1 = para ""
            Thread.new { owner.write(@pa1) }
        end
    end


    @which_port = list_box :items => ["5000", "6000", "7000"],
                           :width => 120,
                           :choose => "5000" do |list|
    end
end
```

You can also investigate the Shoes.APPS method which gives you back an array containing all opened app.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Shoes 4 then it is very likely that the thread doesn't have access to the UI (only the main thread has access to the UI). You could try extracting the value beforehand and then passing it to write as an argument:

```
def write(port)
  #...
end

port = @which_port.text.to_i
@th1 = Thread.new { write(port) }
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that you're also logging in that thread. Not too sure about the Shoes3 thread model, but if it has the same properties as Shoes4 then it might not have access to the UI thread and hence can't print out data. Does it print out data if you simply `puts` the data?